# Destroy the [science] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I think the [science](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) tag should be removed, and maybe even blacklisted from the site. The way it is currently used it does not really mean anything, and I don't really see it being that fruitful of a tag on a site focused on a scientific discipline--everything could be said to be science-related.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are two questions that only have this tag that y'all might want to retag before we leave them untagged when we get rid of this. With only 16 questions using it, though, you could delete it yourself pretty easily. You can't prevent it from being re-created but it may never be if you get rid of it once.

Comment: @Catija I didn't want to do this in a way that drew attention to that many questions on the main page of the site. For our site, that is a relatively large number of questions to make active in a short period, but I understand what you're saying from a resource management perspective. We'll plan the retag campaign.

Comment: @Catija Also, this is a good time to bring up that perhaps mods should have the ability to do this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-burninate-a-tag-themselves/212823#comment1055038_212823

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean. :) It's never fun to have a bunch of older stuff up in your active list It's totally your call how you want to do it... I've seen people either do two at a time over a week and that will take care of them all or do them all in one go like pulling off a band-aid. We're generally happy to help with these requests, particularly with larger volumes (50+). And I see y'all took care of it, so yay! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, the kind of vague, high-level "meta" tag that [science](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) represents is generally discouraged.

I agree - kill it with malice.

Comment: All question retagged. Now we just have to keep an eye on the tag to make sure it doesn't attract new questions.

Comment: @called2voyage If it does, we can blacklist it.